# Rewrite HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(0)')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(1')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(2)')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(3)')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(4)')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><a href='#' onClick=('remove(5)')>Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where the inparameter to remove() is the rownumber. In the remove function I'm removing the row, which means I need to rewrite the rownumbers if want to delete more than once before reloading the page. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Should it always remove the item before?

Comment: I just need to make sure these ID's is up to date before I delete the row :)

Comment: Yeah, but if it's dependent on the actual `index`it would be easier. Does it depend on their index? Or can row 4 remove row 6?

Comment: No, row 4 should only be able to delete row 4 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onclick` from the rows and use jQuery. There is no need to rewrite something then.

```js
$(document).on("click", "a.remove", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a class="remove" href='#'>Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a class="remove" href='#'>Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><a class="remove" href='#'>Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a possibility to use an id or similiar on the links? I'm going to have more links, and I just want the remove link the remove the link?

Comment: Sure, I've changed the answer, @DaveLar!

Comment: Thank you my friend! This is what I'm looking for! I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" though. And I dont understand why, it looks good. Any idea? (on the row "$(this).closest("tr").remove();")

Comment: Yes, I had an error in my code that you have copied. ;) Please copy my js code again. @DaveLar

Comment: Thank you! Here, take a virtual chocolate box!

Comment: You're welcome, @DaveLar!

Comment: Is there btw a chance I can incapsulate this within a function? I need to check if the deletion was successful (in my other code) before I want to remove the row.

Comment: There are different solutions. But without knowing your code I can't show you the beste way. @DaveLar